# How do you verbally distinguish between a single directory in a path and the full path?

Tags: path, c#, terminology

This is a terminology question.

Say you have a path like `C:\foo\bar\MyFolder\`

`foo`, `bar`, and `MyFolder` are all individual directories, also known as folders, right? And they're arranged in a hierarchical directory tree, right?

However, the full path `C:\foo\bar\MyFolder\` may also be referred to as a directory. For example, in C# there's a method called `Directory.GetDirectories()` that returns directories in full path form.

Is there an unambiguous way to refer to the individual items in the path (`foo`, `bar`, and `MyFolder`) that couldn't also mean the full paths ending in those items (`C:\foo\`, `C:\foo\bar\`, and `C:\foo\bar\MyFolder\`)? I mean a word like directory or folder that means only the first thing and can't mean the second.

Comment: The problem is the same for files. Loosely, you can talk about a file/directory `path` to mean the full path, and a file/directory `name` to mean the last component of the path, but whether you can rely on this to be universally understood is another matter. If you are writing anything of some length, you can always define your terms at the head of your piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there an unambiguous way to refer to the individual items in the path

Microsoft refers to these as **components**:

> However, each file system, such as NTFS, CDFS, exFAT, UDFS, FAT, and FAT32, can have specific and differing rules about the formation of the individual **components** in the path to a directory or file.

And:

> Use a backslash `\` to separate the **components** of a path. The backslash divides the file name from the path to it, and one directory name from another directory name in a path.

Source [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)

So you would name them as Path Components.

A full File Path consists of the following components:

- A drive specification
- One or more directory components (delimited by `\` characters)
- A file name component
- A file extension component (starting with the last `.` character in the full filename).

Comment: But how do you refer specifically the last directory component?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I would say the **last** or **final** directory component